# Finding current page number in google search image api

Tags: google-image-search

Is there any way to find out current page number in search complete callback function of google image search api?

I have defined a function for search complete callback and set it using this `setSearchCompleteCallback` and found that it is called for each page click also, so is there any way to know what is the current page number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround, the div for current page has css class 
`gsc-cursor-current-page`

This is not what exactly what I asked in the question but it helped me!